# What's wrong with this code? PHP with OOP

Tags: php, oop, web, server

```
<?php
    class Model
    {
        private $title = "Please define page's title";
        private $body = "Please define page's body";
        private $footer = "Please define page's footer";

        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;
        }

        public function setContent($content)
        {
            $this->body = $content;
        }

        public function setFooter($footer)
        {
            $this->footer = $footer;
        }

        public function showTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }

        public function showContent()
        {
            return $this->body;
        }

        public function showFooter()
        {
            return $this->footer;
        }
    }

    class WebPage extends Model
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            echo '<html>';
            echo '<head>';
            echo '<title>';
            echo $this->showTitle();
            echo '</title>';
            echo '</head>';
            echo '<body>';
            echo $this->showContent();
            echo $this->showFooter();
            echo '</body>';
            echo '</html>';
        }
    }
?>

//In the indeex file
<?php
    $model = new Model();
    $model->setTitle("Php OOP Test");
    $model->setContent("HelloWorld");
    $model->setFooter("Hello");
    $page = new WebPage();
?>
```

The problem is all in the title , content and footer are not changing.

I try to build my own PHP framework.

This looks a little bit stupid but I am new to this kind of thing.

Comment: The constructor gets called when you take an instance of the class; It's unclear what exactly your goal is

Comment: whoa that's not right, you need to do some basic OOP tutorials

Comment: My humble advise would be to start by a smaller project, this being a gigantic one, for which you'll need PHP geniuses

Comment: Why, I think it's fine , because you only access these variables via the class Model

Comment: They're changing, but they're changing in `$model`.... `$page` is a totally different instance of a WebPage, completely unrelated to `$page`.... classes extend classes, not instances extend instance

Comment: All else aside, I'd be 99% certain that in any sort of halfway SOLID MVC setup ... **WebPage** would **not** extend **Model** - to paraphrase @GuillaumeFache - *start with something simpler*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do, what you are trying to do

```
class Model
{
    private $title = "Please define page's title";
    private $body = "Please define page's body";
    private $footer = "Please define page's footer";

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->body = $content;
    }

    public function setFooter($footer)
    {
        $this->footer = $footer;
    }

    public function showTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function showContent()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function showFooter()
    {
        return $this->footer;
    }
}

class WebPage extends Model
{

    public function output() {
        echo '<html>';
        echo '<head>';
        echo '<title>';
        echo $this->showTitle();
        echo '</title>';
        echo '</head>';
        echo '<body>';
        echo $this->showContent();
        echo $this->showFooter();
        echo '</body>';
        echo '</html>';
    }
}
$page = new WebPage();
$page->setTitle("Php OOP Test");
$page->setContent("HelloWorld");
$page->setFooter("Hello");
$page->output();
```

As mentioned in the comments, you were/are instantiating two separate instances of two different classes in your example.  Since `WebPage` is extending `Model`, you only need one `WebPage` instance.  From there, I moved the echo stuff into a separate public method of `Webpage` so it can be called after you have modified the `Model` properties

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new object of your page which is child of the model by `$page = new WebPage();` so you will have this variables for your new object

```
private $title = "Please define page's title";
    private $body = "Please define page's body";
    private $footer = "Please define page's footer";
```

you set the variables like title and content and etc. on another object which is $model

Comment: No it won't - they're `private` scoped not `protected`.

Comment: yes true however the question is edited and completely changed already. otherwise the problem of two different objects was there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct implementation.

Since `WebPage` extends `Model` in inherits all of its functions and variables, so we make a new instance of `WebPage` and then set the `title`, `body`, `footer` with this object.  We then call the `showPage` which is specific to the `WebPage` class that will output all of the variables we set.

```
<?php
    class Model
    {
        private $title = "Please define page's title";
        private $body = "Please define page's body";
        private $footer = "Please define page's footer";

        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;
        }

        public function setContent($content)
        {
            $this->body = $content;
        }

        public function setFooter($footer)
        {
            $this->footer = $footer;
        }

        public function showTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }

        public function showContent()
        {
            return $this->body;
        }

        public function showFooter()
        {
            return $this->footer;
        }
    }

    class WebPage extends Model
    {
        function showPage()
        {
            echo '<html>';
            echo '<head>';
            echo '<title>';
            echo $this->showTitle();
            echo '</title>';
            echo '</head>';
            echo '<body>';
            echo $this->showContent();
            echo $this->showFooter();
            echo '</body>';
            echo '</html>';
        }
    }
?>

//In the index file
<?php
    $page = new WebPage();
    $page->setTitle("Php OOP Test");
    $page->setContent("HelloWorld");
    $page->setFooter("Hello");
    $page->showPage();
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you want to elaborate a bit more, what exactly you changed and why

Comment: @Rizier123 updated, I still think the OP should run though some tutorials there is a basic misunderstanding of `Extends` and OOP